# Display fontawesome icons error

Tags: icons, font-awesome

My website is https://waki.vn, it does not display icon in menu.

http://prntscr.com/khlyka

please help me to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the icon as `<i class="icon-angle-down"></i>`.
Such an icon does not exist.

The proper way to use this icon is `<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>`as you can find out via https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-down?style=solid.

Comment: Hi MBaas, Thank you for your reply. But it show error only frontpage and some page, not all.
For example, this is working:  
https://waki.vn/san-pham/tranh-canvas-muon-tien-xa-hay-hoc-cach-nhin-xa-w148
Please help me why some page has icons is working and other is not. Thank you.

Comment: The icon on that page does not use FontAwesome, but Flaticons ( https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/big_444550#term=angle%20down&page=1&position=1 ). And the page where it works also has a tag to load the .css-file that define this style: `<link data-optimized="2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://waki.vn/min/54806.css">`  It's missing on the first page - if you add this tag to your ´head` it should work!

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for the info! Could you then pls. accept my answer so that the question gets closed?